# Сортировка с точностью наоборот

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос:

```
$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` =
 '$us[users_id]' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY wread DESC LIMIT $otkuda,
 $set_coll_page");
```

который выводит на страницу сообщения пользователя и сортирует их по:

```
1прочитанные - 0не прочитанные.
wread = 0 не прочитанное | wread = 1 прочитанное.
```

дело в том, что при таком запросе сначала выводятся прочитанные сообщения.

Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтоб сначала выводились не прочитанные сообщения?

Comment: Какой запрос - такой результат. Вы сортируете результат в обратном порядке по значению `wread`, а значит сначала будут результаты, где `wread = 1`, что отвечает за прочитанность сообщения

Comment: ключевые слова `desc`/`asc` определяют направление сортировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

порядок [сортировки](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) может быть указан в директиве `order by` оператора `select` после каждого столбца, участвующего в сортировке с помощью ключевых слов `asc` (по возрастанию, порядок по умолчанию) и `desc` (по убыванию):

```
select ... order by col1, col2 asc, col3 desc ...
```