# #1060 - Duplicate column name 'ID'

Tags: mysql

Имеется такой код:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename1 t1, tablename2 t2, tablename3 t3, tablename4 t4, tablename5 t5 

WHERE 
t5.module_id =t4.ID 
AND
t2.tablename1 = t3.ID
AND
t3.tablename1 = t1.ID
AND
t5.tablename2 = t2.ID
```

в итоге выдается таблица с одинковыми названиями столбцов и одинаковыми строками в них.

Мне нужно применить `group by t1.name`  то есть чтобы из выданной объединенной таблице показывались повторяющие строки только один раз.

Если добавляю еще:

```
SELECT* FROM (здесь верхний код) group by t1.name
```

то выдается ошибка:

> #1060 - Duplicate column name 'ID'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь использовать два `select`-а.

для описанного же вами поведения вполне достаточно одного.

пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/632969/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1 (a int, b int);
create table t2 (a int, b int);

insert into t1 values
  (1, 2),
  (3, 4);
insert into t2 values
  (1, 2),
  (3, 4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from t1, t2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/632969/1/0)**:

```
| a | b | a | b |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from t1, t2
group by t1.a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/632969/1/1)**:

```
| a | b | a | b |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
```

Comment: спасибо вроде работает толь выдается таблица в обратном порядке. как ее же отсортировать в обратном порядке то есть чтобы была сначала 3 потом 1

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433116/178576

Comment: да как раз хотел написать desc. Спасибо большое